# Find item from the list

Tags: c#, linq

`equipment` has three items, and `carspecification` is a list item. In the `carspecification`, there is an `equipmentId` property.

How could I able to find equipment item(s) to find only equipment matches with `equipmentId` in `carspecification`.

```
 var equipment = _carService.GetCarEquipment(carId);
 var carSpecification = _carSpecificationService.GetId(specificationId);
```

I have tried the following, but it does not work.

```
 var eq = equipment.Select(x => x.Id.Equals(carSpecification.Select(y=> y.EquipmentId)));
```

Comment: You want `equipment.Where(...)` not `Select`

Comment: @DavidG, could you please provide as an answer? Because, when I have tried where it was giving me string to bool issue.

Comment: I'd rather you remove the question tbh, it's been asked before and isn't particularly helpful to others :)

Comment: is that what you recommend `equipment.Where(x => x.Id.Equals(carSpecification.Select(y=> y.EquipmentId)));`

Comment: @DavidG `equipment.Where(x => x.Id.Equals(carSpecification.Select(y=> y.EquipmentId)));` tried this one, it returned no item even though I expected to see one.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What is `equipment`, is that a list, if so, of what type? If `carspecification` is a class, please provide the class definition.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, it works. Please put as an answer, then I am going to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Any:

```
var result = equipment.Where(e => carSpecification.Any(s => s.specificationId == e.Id));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
equipment.Where(e => carSpecification.Select(c => c.EquipmentId).Contains(e.Id))
```